# Enterprise configuration mandates server certificate but validation is not enabled in Android Wi-Fi network suggestion

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to connect to Enterprise network on android using WiFiManager on Android.

```
@RequiresApi(api = 29)
    public static boolean connectToEnterprise(Context context, String ssid, String identity, String password) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
        enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
        enterpriseConfig.setPhase2Method(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Phase2.MSCHAPV2);
        enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(identity);
        enterpriseConfig.setPassword(password);
        enterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(null);


        WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder();
        builder.setSsid(ssid);
        builder.setWpa2EnterpriseConfig(enterpriseConfig);

        List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> wifiSuggestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        wifiSuggestionsList.add(builder.build());

        int result = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(wifiSuggestionsList);

        if (result == WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Enterprise configuration mandates server certificate but validation is not enabled.
```

I expected it to connect to Wifi Network, but it is throwing this error. I don't know how to give sever certificate.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as you have included two code parts, if I get it correctly one working and one non-working part. Please only remove the working part to make it easier to understand which code part is failing. Or at least place the error message next to the code it belongs to.

Comment: I have remove working code.